# Trouble with ESC & Brushless motor

Tags: arduino, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, drone

I'm new in this group, I hope to be welcome and help you whenever i can.

At first i need your help... i'm assembly a drone ( quadcopter ) , and testing the ESC with the motors, and i have issues.

I buy the next components:
My ESC is the next generical ESC ( from AliExpress ) : https://es.aliexpress.com/item/32837...5b0a63c0qh1PAA
My motors are the next: https://es.aliexpress.com/item/32260...5b0a63c0Pri4Fx
My battery is a 3s battery (11.1 V 3000 mAh ) : https://es.aliexpress.com/item/32963...5b0a63c0Pri4Fx

I'm using Arduino, with the next simple code:

```
        #include <Servo.h>

        Servo ESC1;
        int pot = 0;


        void setup() {

        ESC1.attach(9,1000,2000);

        }

        void loop() {
        pot= analogRead(A0);
        pot = map(pot,0,1023,0,180);
        ESC.write(pot);
        }
```

The output PWM signal is ok ( i think ).. is a 50 Hz signal that change the high width from 1 ms to 2 ms.
well, i connect the circuit as you can see in the attach draw.

My problem is the next:
When i connect the battery the motor make a few sounds like "beeps" and as i saw in the datasheet of the ESC this is ok, but when i turn the potentiometer to set a higher speed to the motor, it spins faster but for a while and then stop. Also, i notice that the temperature of the ESC and the motor increases significantly. I thougt that maybe the ESC is cutoff the signal to the motor for security (due to temperature increases, but when i start again without waiting for temperature drop it makes the same.. )
I try to setting the Throttle Range reading the datasheet of the ESC and apparently it is configured correctly, but it doesnt work ...
I attach photos of my connection.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I hope somebody can help me pls! Thnks

Comment: Hi Brian! thanks for your response!
The PWM signal is 1 and 2 ms in high and then in low, with a frequency of 50 hz...
Maybe have to user 60 hz signal.. but from what i read it works with both frequencies

Comment: Then the information in teh question is wrong.

Comment: You are right! Thanks!!, edited!